# Updating data in MySQL database after inserting in the wrong encoding

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8

I am using PHP and MySQL for saving Arabic data.

My database collation is : `utf8_general_ci`

My database Character set is : `utf8`

At first I did not use `SET NAMES utf8` before insertion so the data was inserted in strange characters in the database but was displayed properly in my application. After using `SET NAMES utf8`, data is inserted properly but the old data is not displayed in Arabic characters even in my application (The new data is ok) .

How can I update all the data to be displayed in Arabic letters in both my application and MySQL database?

**Update**

When I check the encoding of the both of strings ( the one that is inserted and the one that I want to convert to ) using `mb_detect_encoding` function I get that both of the strings are UTF-8 .

Here is an example of the two strings :

the text inserted : `Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ø³Ù… Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ©`
the text I need to convert to : `الإسم بالعربية`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279 -- If that is not sufficient, please provide an example, together with `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM table WHERE ...` to see whether it was even stored correctly.

Comment: this is a row example :

col value :
`Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ø³Ù… Ø¨Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ©`

HEX(col) value : `C398C2A7C399E2809EC398C2A5C398C2B3C399E280A620C398C2A8C398C2A7C399E2809EC398C2B9C398C2B1C398C2A8C399C5A0C398C2A9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You suffer from "double encoding".

Here's what happened.

- The client had characters encoded as utf8; and
- `SET NAMES latin1` lied by claiming that the client had latin1 encoding; and
- The column in the table declared `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Let's walk through what happens to e-acute: `é`.

1. The hex for that, in utf8 is 2 bytes: `C3A9`.
2. `SET NAMES latin1` saw it as 2 latin1-encoded *characters* `Ã` and `©` (hex: `C3` and `A9`)
3. Since the target was `CHARACTER SET utf8`, those 2 characters needed to be converted.
   `Ã` was converted to utf8 (hex `C383`) and `©` (hex `C2A9`)
4. So, 4 bytes were stored (hex `C383C2A9`)

When reading it back out, the reverse steps were performed,
and the end user possibly noticed nothing wrong.  What is wrong:

- The data stored is 2 times as big as it should be (3x for Asian languages).
- Comparisions for equal, greater than, etc may not work as expected.
- `ORDER BY` may not work as expected.

Something like this will repair your data:

```
UPDATE ... SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(
                         CONVERT(UNHEX(col) USING utf8)
                         USING latin1)) USING utf8);
```

[More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#example_of_double_encoding) and 
[More examples of fixing it](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixing_double_encoding_)

Comment: I used Plan A in the second link you have sent and it works better than expected  .. Thanks !

Comment: I should have emphasized that `SET NAMES utf8` is needed to prevent future `INSERTs` from messing up.

Comment: I have just destroyed my table with the last query

Comment: It worked for my when i removed the part `UNHEX`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful [http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,209072,209072

*Same error and solution on MySQL forum. (since 2008)

Comment: This solution is for inserting the data or updating with new data but I want to only change the current data encoding or the way it is displayed .

Comment: Sorry for that, try using [project](http://www.ar-php.org/), bin [Arabic-3.6.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ar-php/files/)
**By original [tread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175053/how-to-convert-arabic-characters-to-unicode-using-php)

Comment: Thanks , It is very useful but not in my case . I updated my question of how the characters are shown .